# What could possibly "break the debugger" in Visual Studio (maybe std::string?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, poco-libraries

Consider setting a breakpoint on the following line, and stepping into it using the Visual Studio debugger (in a fully-cleaned and rebuilt debug build):

```
Poco::URI testUri( "http://somewhere.com/test/path" );
```

It turns out this step in will take you to this function:

```
URI::URI(const char* uri):
    _port(0)
{
    parse(std::string(uri));
}
```

And it turns out that when you take a few steps more and pause on the final line after the `parse()` call, all is well in the newly constructed `URI` object, specifically:

- it has been parsed correctly;
- one can expand the `this` pointer to see correctly assigned member variables (e.g. its_host, _path and _scheme members are set to "somewhere.com", "/test/path" and "http" respectively);
- the `this` pointer at this stage points to a legitimate memory (e.g. 0x002AEE20) location, and at that location one can see what I am confident is the URI object (a set of `std::string` variables, and one `int` as it happens).

However, after a single step more, one returns to the original code line, and suddenly:

- expanding the `testUri` object in the "Autos" or "Watch" debugger windows leads to `std::string` members that cannot be read (there are "errors reading characters of string"), and yet...
- the memory where the constructed object resides remains unchanged, and...
- the address of `testUri` is confirmed to point to the unchanged memory

How can this be? Is the VS debugger broken? What broke it?

This is the latest in a sequence of weird issues trying to get POCO Libraries up and going in a multi-threaded MFC project. I have no idea if the MFC or the multi-threading should have any impact on Poco, but I have experienced a week of weirdness -- often with `std::string` objects involved -- and I'd like to get to the bottom of it. All suggestions for tracing what is occurring greatly appreciated. I'm running VS2015 Community if that make a difference.

Comment: Do you have a small repro that can be posted?  You might need to also post download locations of the specific Poco library builds you're using and the build options you're using.

Comment: Maybe something - your application or the library - is compiled in release mode? Optimizations and lack of debug information can cause the debugger to show weird stuff. For example, your object may reside entirely or partially in registers and have no actual representation in the memory.

Comment: Thanks for the tips... I'm checking. What I can report is that the Poco libraries are supposed to be automatically selected and linked according to various compiler switches. I have a multi-threaded debug build... which should mean that PocoFoundationmtd.lib is linked. However... if I rename PocoFoundationmtd.lib so it can't be found, then my application still builds. That sounds like a pretty solid clue :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, trying to mix different builds (i.e. both release and debug) within the same project can cause issues like this.

In this case, however, it was the mixing of different compilers -- most of the project was built under what seem to be VS2010 conditions, while the Poco libraries were built under VS2015 conditions.

I'm not 100% sure of the conditions under which the wider project was being compiled before, since it was recently upgraded from VS2010 to VS2015, and in the process, the `Platform Toolset` setting did not show up in the `.vcxproj` file. I have now (re-)introduced a `Platform Toolset` for each build configuration and set it to `v100`, and also rebuilt Poco with the `build_vs100.cmd` script. Everything seems to work as expected now.

The way I tracked this down was to observe that the application was being compiled with `/MDd` (multi-threaded debug DLL code generation), yet the linker was attempting to link to the "d" versions of the Poco libraries, not the "mdd" versions. When the compilers were brought into line, the linker correctly linked the "mdd" versions as one would expect.

Since all library linking in Poco is intended to be automatic (see the `#pragma` directives in `PocoFoundation.h`), the incorrect library selection was due to changed preprocessor definitions (`POCO_STATIC` was not being defined). I did not bother to check why this was.